# Update post meta not working in transition_post_status

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I am developing a plugin for custom post type which take the link from the title of the post and then after scraping on that link it updates all things like post title, post permalink and post_meta. Now its only updating the title and the link but not the post meta, I have tried debugging the data.

```
function a_new_post($new_status, $old_status, $post)
{

    if ('publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status)
        return;
    $new_slug = sanitize_title($post->post_title);
    if ('aps-products' !== $post->post_type)
        return; // restrict the filter to a specific post type

    $result= getSpecs($post->post_title);

/*
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
*/
$groups = get_aps_cat_groups(16);
$groups_data = get_aps_groups_data();
$attrs_data = get_aps_attributes_data();

// get aps attributes data from input fields

foreach ($groups as $groupId) {
    $group_data = $groups_data[$groupId];
    $group_values = get_aps_product_attributes($post->ID, $groupId); 
    if ($group_data['attrs']) {
        if (aps_is_array($group_data['attrs'])) {
            $first=array();
            $value='';
            foreach ($group_data['attrs'] as $attr_id) {
                switch($attr_id){
                    case 20:
                        $value=$result[1];
                    break;
                    case 21:
                        $value=$result[12];
                    break;
                    case 22:
                        $value=$result[3];
                    break;
                    case 24:
                        $value=$result[13];
                    break;
                }
                $frist[$attr_id]=$value;
            }
            update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'aps-attr-group-' .$groupId, $first );
        }
    }
}



/*
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
*/

    $post_update = array(
        'ID'         => $post->ID,
        'post_title' => $result[0].' '.$result[1]
    );
    if (!wp_is_post_revision($post->ID)) {
        wp_update_post($post_update);
        $new_slug = sanitize_title($result[0].' '.$result[1]);
        if ($post->post_name != $new_slug) {
            wp_update_post(
                array(
                    'ID'        => $post->ID,
                    'post_name' => $new_slug

                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `transition_post_status` hook fires twice, and both times, it's before postmeta is available. `save_post` hook fires after it and the last run of `save_post` does contain the postmeta, so I'd try using that hook but also making sure you're only firing it once, when postmeta is normally present.

Comment: I tried doing it with the save_post hook but no success.

Comment: Basic debugging: try simplifying down to the essentials. Fire something super simple on `save_post`, like `fwrite` a timestamp to a text file. You'll then see how many times it's running. Once you determine how to isolate just the one time you want it to run, then start building out the more complex logic by first checking whether the old postmeta even exists. If it does, then start building out the update.

Comment: I have changed it to save_post and it is only firing once, it is also updating the array in the post array but the problem is that every index the value is blank.